# How to use phpactor.el in GNU Emacs 25.2.2

Tags: completion, php-mode

I am a Vim user for about a year now and I am curious to give Emacs a try. I discover Emacs for some days now and I would like to improve my PHP-editing experience.
In Vim there is a [plugin](https://phpactor.github.io/phpactor/vim-plugin.html) for [phpactor](https://phpactor.github.io/phpactor), a smart autocompletion tool for PHP, as it's done in IDE.
There is also an Emacs [plugin](https://github.com/emacs-php/phpactor.el) (in alpha version as of writing), and I can't get it to work.

To install Phpactor I followed the [documentation](https://phpactor.github.io/phpactor/standalone.html), so I have a global `phpactor` command that I can use.
As an example here is the output when I run it in my Terminal:

```
$ phpactor status
Version: 7db7a5c (3 weeks ago) updated-composer-749
Filesystems: git, simple, composer
Working directory: /var/www/html/work/libs/myrepo

Config files (missing is not bad):

  ✘ /home/john/.config/phpactor/phpactor.json
  ✘ /home/john/config/phpactor/phpactor.yml
  ✘ /var/www/html/work/libs/myrepo/.phpactor.json
  ✘ /var/www/html/work/libs/myrepo/.phpactor.yml

Diagnostics:

  ✔ Composer detected - faster class location and more features!
  ✔ Git detected - enables faster refactorings in your repository scope!
  ✔ XDebug is disabled. XDebug has a negative effect on performance.
```

By viewing so, I think it's installed successfully.
In Emacs I installed the plugin by using the command `package-install phpactor`.
My `~/.emacs` contains the following as suggested by the plugin documentation:

```lisp
(add-hook 'php-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (make-local-variable 'eldoc-documentation-function)
            (setq eldoc-documentation-function
                  'phpactor-hover)))
```

Now that everything is installed I would like to use it and I don't know how to. I think phpactor is called when I am about to call a method on a variable, but I only see an error in the mini buffer. Here is an example:

```php
function thing() {
    $a = new Stuff();
    $a->|
    return 1;
}
```

When my cursor is just after the arrow (where I put a pipe `|`), I see the following in the mini buffer:

```
Phpactor: Unknown item "return", known items: "return", "return", "return"
```

In Vim I only need to install the plugin and type `C-x C-o` to have a context menu with the suggested method names.
How to use it in Emacs?

Comment: Ensure that you have `phpactor.el` installed according to its [directions](https://github.com/emacs-php/phpactor.el). Barring that, understand that `phpactor.el` is _alpha_ quality software. Your best bet for getting help may be to [open an issue](https://github.com/emacs-php/phpactor.el/issues) at its [github page](https://github.com/emacs-php/phpactor.el).

Comment: I understand it's in _alpha_ for now. I think I've installed it the right way, but I'll open an issue on its Github page, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the @nega's advice and I've submitted a Github [issue](https://github.com/emacs-php/phpactor.el/issues/113).

In short, the part in my `~/.emacs` was problematic, I had to delete it. I mean this part:

```lisp
(add-hook 'php-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (make-local-variable 'eldoc-documentation-function)
            (setq eldoc-documentation-function
                  'phpactor-hover)))
```

Also there is no keybindings by default and I didn't know it.

**EDIT**:

Finally I used the `bind-key` plugin to map keys and phpactor functions, like this :

```lisp
(require 'bind-key)
(bind-key* "C-p C-d" 'phpactor-goto-definition)
(bind-key* "C-p C-i" 'phpactor-implement-contracts)
(bind-key* "C-p C-g" 'phpactor-generate-method)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my code. Yes the documentation is awful for phpactor and it takes some digging. I have this currently and it shows how to use transients and bind them to a key in php-mode. Hopefully useful to someone.

```
 (use-package transient
   :ensure t)

 (use-package phpactor 
   :ensure t)

 (use-package company-phpactor 
   :ensure t)

 (use-package php-mode
   ;;
   :hook (
          (php-mode . (lambda () 
                        (make-local-variable 'eldoc-documentation-function)
                        (setq eldoc-documentation-function
                              'phpactor-hover)
                        (set (make-local-variable 'company-backends)
                             '(;; list of backends
                               company-phpactor
                               company-files))
                        (lsp)
                        )))
   :config
   (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html\\.twig\\'" . web-mode))
   (define-transient-command php-transient-menu ()
     "Php"
     [["Class"
       ("cc" "Copy" phpactor-copy-class)
       ("cn" "New" phpactor-create-new-class)
       ("cr" "Move" phpactor-move-class)
       ("ci" "Inflect" phpactor-inflect-class)
       ("n"  "Namespace" phpactor-fix-namespace)]
      ["Properties"
       ("a"  "Accessor" phpactor-generate-accessors)
       ("pc" "Constructor" phpactor-complete-constructor)
       ("pm" "Add missing props" phpactor-complete-properties)
       ("r" "Rename var locally" phpactor-rename-variable-local)
       ("R" "Rename var in file" phpactor-rename-variable-file)]
      ["Extract"
       ("ec" "constant" phpactor-extract-constant)
       ("ee" "expression" phpactor-extract-expression)
       ("em"  "method" phpactor-extract-method)]
      ["Methods"
       ("i" "Implement Contracts" phpactor-implement-contracts)
       ("m"  "Generate method" phpactor-generate-method)]
      ["Navigate"
       ("x" "List refs" phpactor-list-references)
       ("X" "Replace refs" phpactor-replace-references)
       ("."  "Goto def" phpactor-goto-definition)]
      ["Phpactor"
       ("s" "Status" phpactor-status)
       ("u" "Install" phpactor-install-or-update)]])

   (define-key php-mode-map (kbd "C-p") 'php-transient-menu))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The _transient command_ are only key binding? How do you use them?